# Find volume of the solid obtained

Tags: calculus

Find volume of the solid obtained by rotating about the y-axis the region bounded by $y= 4-(x-4)^2$ and $y = 0$.

Comment: You should do more than just typing your question for us to solve. I have no idea what the upvote ion the question s about. Please always include your effort and where you are stuck when you ask the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

$$V = \int\limits_{x=2}^6 2 \pi x (4 - (x-4)^2)\ dx = \frac{256 \pi }{3}$$

---

*Mathematica* code:

```
aa = RegionPlot3D[0 < y < 4 - (Sqrt[x^2 + z^2] - 4)^2 ,
   {x, -6, 6},
   {y, 0, 4},
   {z, -6, 6},
   PlotPoints -> 100,
   PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5],
   BoxRatios -> {10, 4, 10},
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0},
   AxesStyle -> {{Thick, Red}, {Thick, Red}, {Thick, Red}}];
bb = Graphics3D[{Blue, Opacity[0.2], 
    InfinitePlane[{0, 0, 0}, {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}]}];
cc = RegionPlot3D[3 < Sqrt[x^2 + z^2] < 3.2 && 0 < y < (4 - (3 - 4)^2),
   {x, -6, 6},
   {y, 0, 4},
   {z, -6, 6},
   PlotStyle -> Directive[{Opacity[0.5], Green}],
   PlotPoints -> 150];
Show[aa, bb, cc]
```

Comment: Nice! Could you please share the Mathematica code you used? Thank you in advance

Comment: Perhaps after I get upvoted and accepted...